# Issue with file upload in one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I'm using an **icon instead of the regular upload input + submit button.** 
I want the upload to starts automatically right after a file is chosen.
Once the user selects a file, nothing happens though.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="upload"  type="file" name="image"  style="display:none" value=/>
  <input name="wishid" type="hidden" value=/>
  <img id="upload_img" src="/images/upload.png">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#upload_img').click(function(){
  $('#upload').click();
 });
</script>
```

What do I need to add to the jQuery code to actually start the upload process via upload.php ?

Comment: Add a change event handler to the file input that, when invoked, submits the form.  The change handler is called when the user selects a file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this description of how to replace input:file with image](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) and then you can just use the code below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#upload_img').click(function(){
    $('form').submit();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work: Nothing happens when i click on the icon, cant browse and select files anymore.

Comment: Remove everything inside the `.submit()` method parantheses and try it.

Comment: Okay so now when i click on the icon, it redirects to upload.php right away : i can't browse/select a file.

Comment: and now? Does it ask for the filename?

Comment: Yes it does, but i dont have time to choose a file, i can see the URL redirecting to upload.php right away...

Comment: Did you look at the link I added about replacing the input:file with an image?

Comment: Yes, i did check your link, but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I did find a working solution, i added this to my jquery script: document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("upload_icon").submit();      And i added a ID attribute to my form called "upload_icon".